# How to handle "Say Congrats" notification on LinkedIn, if it is already handled?

Tags: linkedin

So, LinkedIn has "Home", where you have a roll of posts from your contacts. There, usually I'm notified if they have a anniversary or something, and I usually like/comment there.

But then, EVEN if I liked/commented from there, when I go to Notifications part of LinkedIn, I still have a notification for "Congratulate XX on XX" - even if I just did that several seconds ago!

One would think, a company as rich as Microsoft could have figured out to pay a developer, so that "IF (user commented on post X) THEN (do not show "Say Congrats" notification for post X)" - but I guess, they'd never be that rich if they actually tried to be useful :)

So how do I handle these stupid notifications? There are options there to Delete, Unfollow, and Turn Off - but I don't want to use neither; I want to say "Handled" or something, because that is what I did few seconds ago?